# How to vertically align text in the middle

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

In my wordpress posts I have a div that is half image half text. On the side where the text is I want to vertically align the text in the middle.  I have tried vertical-align:middle but it did not work. Does anyone have any solutions? Thanks in advance.

css

```css
.half-width-img{
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.half-width-text{
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
padding:0 100px 0 100px;
    text-align: justify;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.half-image-half-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-image-half-text">
    <img class="half-width-img" src="IMAGE URL" />
    <p class="half-width-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use float, but display :)

***test snippet in full page mode***

- `display:inline-block;` and html comments to erase the `white-space` :

```css
.half-width-img {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.half-width-text {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
  text-align: justify;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.half-image-half-text {
}
```

```html
<div class="half-image-half-text">
  <img class="half-width-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100" /><!--
  --><p class="half-width-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
    Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
    mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
</div>
```

- `display:table;` and 2 containers for each content so content can be `vertical-align` to middle. the tallest will set wich one will align to center

```css
.half-width-img ,
.half-width-text {
  display: table-cell;
  width:50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
.half-width-text {
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.half-width-img img{
  width:100%;
  }
.half-image-half-text {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-image-half-text">
  <div  class="half-width-img"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100" /></div>
  <p class="half-width-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
    Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
    mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
</div>
```

- or `display:flex;` `flex:1;` will spray both evenly, `margin:auto` will manage visually the `vertical-align`

```css
.half-width-img {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto;
}
.half-width-text {
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 100px 0 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.half-image-half-text {display:flex;}
```

```html
<div class="half-image-half-text">
  <img class="half-width-img" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100" />
  <p class="half-width-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus.
    Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
    Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum.
    Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla
    mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question but I think you are looking for `line-height`. You can try `line-height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean center text in div? Then use text-align:center

```css
.half-width-img{
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.half-width-text{
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
padding:0 100px 0 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.half-image-half-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
 Run code snipp
```

```html
<div class="half-image-half-text">
<img class="half-width-img" src="http://s27.postimg.org/3q7ppnkyr/microsoft.jpg" /><p class="half-width-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the paragraph use an absolute position based on the relative position of the parent. Then translate the position.

```css
.half-width-img{
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
}
.half-width-text{
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: white;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.half-image-half-text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-image-half-text">
  <img class="half-width-img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  <p class="half-width-text">text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Flexbox.

```css
 .half-image-half-text {
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
}
.half-width-img, .half-width-text {
  width: 50%;
}
.half-width-text {
  padding: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-image-half-text">
  <img class="half-width-img" src="http://placehold.it/300x400">
  <p class="half-width-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.
  </p>
</div>
```